# compareGroups p.overall missing p-value

Tags: nonparametric

I was doing a non-parametric test across multiple groups in compareGroups.  What is strange is my p-overall is missing after showing <.01 before. AND the distribution of the data in the clusters had not changed from before.

Is there any reasonable reason why it might be missing (I can't find in documentation)? Especially when the data did not change from before and p-value was <.01?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is "compareGroups" an app, or is it a routine within an app? Or is it a standard process that I should know about.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. It is a package within R.  Basically I did a categorical test between two groups (was wrong about initial test) and if the data meets groups >5 does a chi-square test. Otherwise, a Fishers Exact test.